# is there any method to re-render the screen to bottom tab nav v5 in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

Hy, I'm using react-native bottom tabs navigation the first time I'm having an issue to re-render the screen when I get back to some other tab. I try to use **isFocused** in useEffect() but it didn't work for me.

```
const LandScreen = ({navigation}) => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      
      tabBarOptions={{
        showLabel: false,
        activeTintColor: colors.primary,
        inactiveTintColor: colors.textHead,
      }}
      
      >
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={HomeScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({focused, color, size}) => {
            const icon = focused ? 'home' : 'home';
            return <Icon name={icon} color={color} size={size} />;
          },
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Message"
        component={ChatStackScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({focused, color, size}) => {
            const icon = focused ? 'chatbox-ellipses' : 'chatbox-ellipses';
            return <Icon name={icon} color={color} size={size} />;
          },
          
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Requests"
        component={RequestStackScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({focused, color, size}) => {
            const icon = focused ? 'heart' : 'heart';
            return <Icon name={icon} color={color} size={size} />;
          },
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Notifications"
        component={NotificationStackScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({focused, color, size}) => {
            const icon = focused ? 'notifications' : 'notifications';
            return <Icon name={icon} color={color} size={size} />;
          },
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Profile"
        component={ProfileScreenScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({focused, color, size}) => {
            const icon = focused ? 'person' : 'person';
            return <Icon name={icon} color={color} size={size} />;
          },
          
        }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};
```

Each Tab component having a stack inside of it.

Someone informs me how to rerender the bottom navigation tabs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want the screen to re-render when you click on a bottom tab navigation button.

This can be accomplished by either adding the 'focus' event listener via the react navigation docs https://reactnavigation.org/docs/function-after-focusing-screen/

Or by explicitly calling 'navigation.navigate' when a bottom tab is pressed.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming I understand your question, all you want to do is re-render the icons when the tab changes?

React Navigation has docs & an example for this use-case for tab-based navigation [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-based-navigation/#customizing-the-appearance).

Posting the code sample from the docs here for ease-of-access:

```
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';

// (...)

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator
        screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
            let iconName;

            if (route.name === 'Home') {
              iconName = focused
                ? 'ios-information-circle'
                : 'ios-information-circle-outline';
            } else if (route.name === 'Settings') {
              iconName = focused ? 'ios-list-box' : 'ios-list';
            }

            // You can return any component that you like here!
            return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />;
          },
          tabBarActiveTintColor: 'tomato',
          tabBarInactiveTintColor: 'gray',
        })}
      >
        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

**If your question meant re-rendering the screen when the tab changes:**

Leveraging `useEffect` with `useIsFocused` should work when changing tabs. You haven't included your example with those hooks, so I'm not exactly sure how you're using it.

The following snippet should get you up and running with said hooks. In this case, you can run whatever you want inside the `useEffect` when switching tabs, where the active tab gets triggered.

If for some reason you just want the UI to get updated/persisted based on some data between tab changes you might want to consider using [Redux](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-based-navigation/#customizing-the-appearance).

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Text, View } from "react-native";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";
import { useIsFocused } from "@react-navigation/core";

function HomeScreen() {
  const isFocused = useIsFocused();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isFocused) {
      console.log("HELLO HOME");
    }
  }, [isFocused]);

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
      <Text>Home!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function SettingsScreen() {
  const isFocused = useIsFocused();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isFocused) {
      console.log("HELLO SETTINGS");
    }
  }, [isFocused]);

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
      <Text>Settings!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Baily's answer, I added isFocused to the return.
In my case I have a webView, so now I have:

```
return (
isFocused && (
  <WebView>...</WebView>
));
```

Without the logic "isFocused &&" the content of the tab didn't re-render